# Installed HelloWorld app on physical Android device through Eclipse. How do I find it on phone?

Tags: eclipse, adb, smartphone, android

The console in Eclipse says this:

```
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-03-10 17:46:08 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
[2014-03-10 17:46:17 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'TA88307T9S'
[2014-03-10 17:46:17 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2014-03-10 17:46:19 - MyFirstApp] Success!
[2014-03-10 17:46:19 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
[2014-03-10 17:46:19 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

That is after importing a Hello World app from online. Now I was hoping to find an app icon on my phone to launch it, but I can't find it. How do I launch the app?

My manifest xml file now looks like this, after Merlevede's answer:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</application>

</manifest>
```

But issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No Launcher activity found!

As the logs saying that you do not have Launcher Activity. To solve this make any activity as laucher as per your requirement

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Android Manifest xml file. You're missing some of these lines for your Main Activity (either the `MAIN` action, or the `LAUNCHER` category).

```
<activity android:name="mx.company.app.ActivityMain" android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```